# Есть аналогия autopep8 для JS или PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть аналогия autopep8 для JS или PHP? Авто линтеры для файлов. Если есть то напишите их пожалуйста. Желательно чтобы работало в любом редакторе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для JS посмотрите:

https://eslint.org/

https://prettier.io/

https://rome.tools/

Сам использую eslint из командной строки, но вроде бы должны быть плагины для редакторов.